# How to connect MSSQL with Python without using ODBC

Tags: python, jdbc, database-connection, mssql-jdbc

How to connect MSSQL with Python without using the ODBC driver?

I have tried with ODBC but am stuck with this error-- `pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Is it possible to connect MSSQL Database with Python easily using JDBC

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but ODBC works great. What have you tried? How is your connection string? Can the server be directly connected (e.g. by MS SSMS)?